# SQL query returning same value for both tables colums

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
  (COUNT(v1.id) * 2) + (COUNT(v2.id) * 0.5) AS total,
  COUNT(v1.id) AS votes,
  COUNT(v2.id) AS visits
FROM
   votes AS v1,
   visits AS v2
;
```

Actually this query results in 1710 for votes and visits but votes has 18 rows and visits 98... Anyone know why? And has any solution?

The correct return values would be:
Total of 85
18 Votes
98 Visits

Current structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7604/1

Comment: How are you supposed to get the '85' value? What are your table structures?

Comment: Just a bunch of id's with auto increment
18 rows of votes and 98 rows of visits (typed wrong in question, just noticed now)

Comment: no link between the tables?

Comment: nothing, just selecting both at same time

Comment: but you cannot do it this way .. as said by Roman, you are cross joining your tables, you are not just 'unioning' them.

Comment: Current: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7604/1 values are diffent from here.

Comment: Ok we have your "table structure". What's your desired output for this test data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT SUM(VisitsCount) + SUM(VotesCount) AS TOTAL,  SUM(VisitsCount) AS VISITS, SUM(VotesCount) AS VOTES
FROM (

  SELECT COUNT(id) AS VotesCount, 0 AS VisitsCount, 1 AS Gr
  FROM votes

  UNION 

  SELECT 0 AS VotesCount, COUNT(ID) AS VisitsCount, 1 AS Gr
  FROM visits

  ) t 

GROUP BY Gr
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7604/19)

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Here's how I'll use it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2c376/1/0
What was this `)t` after all this FROM? never seen such thing...

Comment: Glad I could help... :), `t` is just a alias to the selected data (table), (like `AS t`).

Answer (score 3):

What you doing here called cross join or cross product - for each row from votes you're taking all rows from visits.

Comment: Any solution about it?

Comment: Please provide your table structure. It would be even better if you give some test data and desired output.

Comment: Current: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7604/1 values are diffent from here.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the UNION operation instead of the CROSS JOIN you are doing

It would look like:

```
SELECT 
  whatever
FROM
   (SELECT whatever1 FROM votes) AS v1 UNION (SELECT whatever2 FROM visits) AS v2
```

I do not know how the syntax would be in mySQL, and I do question the possibility to list these 3 values with one single 'select' instruction. Even if it's doable, it's definitely not worth the headache!!!